# Moving (not copying) property inside object - using reference

Tags: javascript, reference, javascript-objects

How do I **move** an array element, to another location in the tree?

Assuming:

```
obj = [
  {
    x : [{/*obj*/},{/*obj*/}]
    },
  {
    x : [{/*obj*/},{/*obj*/}]
    },
  {
    x : [
         {/*obj*/}, 
         {/*obj*/},
         {
            x:[]
          }
      ]
    }
]
```

And assuming that i can only use `a` and `b`

```
var a = obj[1];
var b = obj[2].x[2].x;
```

How can I move `obj[1]` into `obj[2].x[3].x` using `obj[2].x[3].push()`?

---

edit

i made a mistake - posting a one level array/object, like this it is easy. but how can it be done with deeper objects?
data sample changed.

note: what i ask is - how can i move an array-element from random position, while keeping the rest intact (like removing an object from dom)

thanks

Comment: Looks like an invalid object, without keys ?

Comment: @adeneo correct. thanks. fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood but it seems like you posted exactly what your want to do? What is the problem?

**Edit**: Updated the answer with new obj and using a and b variables.

```js
var objArr = [{
  x: [{ /*obj*/ }, { /*obj*/ }]
}, {
  x: [{ /*obj*/ }, { /*obj*/ }]
}, {
  x: [{ /*obj*/ }, { /*obj*/ }, {
    x: []
  }]
}];

var a = objArr[1];
var b = objArr[2].x[2].x;
b.push(a);
console.log("Checking if same Object: " + (b[0] === a));
objArr.splice(1, 1);

console.log(objArr);
```

Comment: @yossi Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to remove item from an array and then push as you proposed. Notice that splice will return removed object or array of removed objects:

```
var obj = [ ... ];

var elem = obj.splice(1, 1);
obj[1].x[2].x.push(elem);
```